# Has Tom Hardy's portrayal of Bane influenced any other Batman media?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

Tom Hardy's portrayal of Bane, or I guess you could say Christopher Nolan's directorial take on Bane from *The Dark Knight Rises* seemed to prove very popular although different than any other appearances of Bane I can recall.

I had noticed Bane's physical appearance in *Arkham Origins* was somewhat similar and was more of a militaristic leader than I've seen in other media. Other than that one game, I don't follow the current comics and I'm curious if any recent comics, games or other media since the film was released have taken any cues from his portrayal?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, Bane's appearance has been altered even in the comics, fusing the old and new costumes together. This shouldn't be a surprise as comics will often infuse new ideas into their medium from other sources if they become popular in the new medium, such as Bane's look in Arkham Asylum.

They took the two looks and merged them together and kept the old mask. New media video games have also taken on what I call the Fusion Bane look.

[image]

Old School Bane Classic

[image]

Fusion Bane for Arkham Asylum

[image]

Dark Knight Bane, Paramilitary look

[image]

Fusion Bane for New 52 DC Universe

[image]

Bane from Arkham Origins

This last Bane resembles elements of Tom Hardy's interpretation of Bane, such as wearing a flak vest with numerous devices under his coat, being bald, leading an army of mercenaries from a hideout in the sewers, and knowing Batman's identity as Bruce Wayne.

Comment: *Batman: Arkham Asylum* was released in 2009, before *The Dark Knight Rises* started filming.

Comment: Sorry, screwed up the order of the images. Will move them to the proper arrangement...

Comment: Bane has known that Batman was really Bruce Wayne since the *Knightfall* story arc, published 1993-94.

Comment: "from other sources" - the most famous example probably being Harley Quinn

Answer (score 0):

The clearest example I can see is in the *Injustice: God's Among Us* video game. The "Regime Bane" version of the character wears a mask that actually has some molded/shaped parts, as opposed to one that is simply a pull-over-your-head luchador mask:

[image: Bane Regime]

Comment: I would say this has no elements of the Tom Hardy version of Bane.  That mask looks more like a Goalie/Jason Vorhees mask than the one used in TDKR.

Comment: @Monty129 Indeed it does, but it's the only other version of the character I've seen where the mask seems more skeletal than cloth. Every other incarnation I've seen it's just a cloth mask. Maybe the similarity is more a similar visceral impression than anything else.